# Use of undeclared type 'URL' in textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:)

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I am currently working on a simple app that retrieves some text and sets some UITextView's to the text with link autodetection enabled, and whilst attempting to allow the user to tap on the link, I have run into this issue whereby whilst attempting to implement the UITextView delegate to enable link redirection, the parser gives the error of: `Use of undeclared type 'url'`

If I try and use the newer version of textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:), the parser also gives the same: `Use of undeclared type` error for the UITextItemInteraction

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 10 or later?

Comment: Right now, in base project settings, I've got it set to 9.3 (it says latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation on that method. There is actually a fourth argument of type `UITextItemInteraction`. It is most likely declared optional and when you don't list it in your definition it just assumes you don't care about it, but it's still there. And it turns out `UITextItemInteraction` is only available in iOS 10 and later. If Xcode thinks 9.3 is the latest, your Xcode is out of date. You should update to Xcode 8. You can still target iOS 9 if you really want, but you'll need to mark that method as only available for iOS 10, something the Xcode 8 compiler errors should walk you through.

Comment: Thanks for the info - however, as I said, the issue of URL being a supposed undeclared type occurs whether or not the UITextItemInteraction part is present.

Comment: No, 7.3.1 though the App Store is not saying an update is existent - however if I go to the XCode app on the store, it says the newest version is 8.0 but says 'get' instead of 'update'.

Comment: I'm still convinced that what I mentioned in my answer is your problem. Whether you include `UITextItemInteraction` or not, it is still technically there. And both that and `URL` is only a valid type in Xcode 8. You should either get Xcode 8 from the store or from developer.apple.com, and if you want to use that method, you should convert your project to Swift 3.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see the 'only in XCode 8' part of your answer.
You are correct, thanks!
and sorry haha

Answer (score 0):

Check the method definition given below

`func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        return true
    }`

Comment: `URL` is a perfectly valid Swift type in Swift 3, and this should not cause the problem as the newer version of this method does indeed declare it with a `URL` instead of `NSURL`.

Comment: Also, NSURL returns an error as the function being overridden uses URL